# React Native build on Older Android has wrong font colors, spacing and no icons

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I am using managed development using expo (v 49.0.8) and React Native (0.72.6). For the displays in question I am using react-native-paper (5.10.6).  I  have three basic problems:

1. The icons - no icons show up on a very old Android. They work fine on all other iOS and Androids (hundreds of different ones). I am using the Material-Community icons.
2. Most text is "white" and some is "yellow" and come out black on this one android. I am using default fonts. Works fine on all other devices that have used it.
3. The space available for the Bottom Tabs text(from React Native) is about 3 characters - the rest are cut off. It works fine on all other devices.

This failing device/ Model Name is: MT104SIP; Mfg: HOOZO; Android version is 8.1.0.

Thanks for answering this.